# How to get the value as props in a different component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

In my react application, I have three parallel components. In my first component, I am doing an API call and based on the response I am routing the flow to Validated or Non-Validated Component.

Once the user is routed to validated component, there is a button on click of which user should be redirected to another component which should display the data in API response (first component) as key value pair. I am using Redux for state management.

The issue I am facing is the data is dispatched as an empty object from the store. I am not sure where I am going wrong but when I am debugging the app, I see the the action is not getting dispatched to the store and it's always returning me the initial state.

action.js-

```
export const setPoiData = (poiData)  => dispatch => {
    console.log('inside actions');
    dispatch({
        type: SET_POI_DATA, 
        payload: poiData
    })
}
```

Reducer.js-

```
const initialState = {
    poiData: {},
}

const reducerFunc = (state = initialState, action)  => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_POI_DATA:
        console.log('inside poi reducers');
            return {...state,poiData: action.payload}    
        default: return {...state}
    }
}

Component 1-

//API call
```

Detail Component-

To get the data from store I am doing something like below-

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.poiData)
 }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        poiData: state.poiData,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setPoiData(data) {
    dispatch(setPoiData(data));
  }
})
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Can someone suggest me how to proceed ahead on this?

Answer (score 0):

inside **componentDidMount()** you must call action like this `this.props.setPoiData(<your data here>);`